# Not appending the desired output in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following (very incomplete) code that I want to eventually be a shopping cart using jquery.

This is code for loading items remotely from a json file and parsing them into Html using jquery.

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
                "use strict";
            // Download the content
            var head = $("<h1>Aisan Market</h1>");
        var dl = $("<dl>");
            $("body")
                .append(head)
                .append(dl)
        for (var i = 0; i <shop.length; i++) {
            var item = shop[i];
            var dt=$("<dt>").text(item.itemId)
            var dt1 = $("<dt>").text(item.name)
            var dd = $("<dd>").text(item.price)
            var button = $("<button>buy</button>");
            dl
                .append(button)
                .append(dt)
                .append(dt1)
                .append(dd);

        }
```

Here I'd like to have on a button click to walk the dom tree to the correct item id,item name and price and append that to the cart.but it's not doing that.It's writing the id number repeating it and writing 0.

```
        var cart = $("<div>cart<div>");
        $("body").append(cart);

      var total = 0;
        $("button").on("click", function () {

                var a = $(this);
            var prev = a.next("dt").text();

               var b = $(this);
            var prev1 = b.next("dt").text();

                var c = $(this);
            var prev2 = c.next("dd").text();

            total += prev2;


            cart
               .append(prev)
               .append(prev1)
               .append(total);
        });
    });
```

Where am I going wrong.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Create snippet/jsfiddle to explain the problem

Comment: Each of `a`, `b` and `c` are the same so consider what happens when you use `next('dt')`. I suggest you add some classes to your elements (eg `name`, `price`, etc) and use something like `a.parent().find('.name')`